# Как корректно проверить input на заполнение?

Tags: javascript, html

Делаю калькулятор на `js`. Есть два поля типа `number`, поле с выводом результата и панель кнопок "+", "-"... sin cos...

Если со сложением и подобными ему операциями (с двумя операндами) у меня не возникло проблем, то с такими как sin и т.д, что делать не пойму. Нужно проверить случаи:

1. когда заполнено только первое поле - взять синус из первого поля
2. заполнено только второе поле - взять синус из него
3. заполнены оба поля - ошибка
4. не заполнены поля — сунус 0

Проверяю так:

```
function sin (){

var firstValue = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
var secondValue = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;

var output =0;

if (firstValue == 0 && secondValue !=0) output = Math.sin(secondValue);
if (secondValue == 0 && firstValue !=0) output = Math.sin(firstValue);

if (firstValue ==0 && secondValue ==0) output =Math.sin(0);

else alert("Заполните только одно поле!");

document.getElementById("result").value = output; 
}
```

Проблема в том, что когда я не заполняю или первое или второе поле, скрипт все равно переходит на

```
 else alert("Заполните только одно поле!");
```

хотя должно работать одно из двух первых условий, ведь когда не заполняю оба поля синус 0 спокойно выводит. Замена нулей в условиях на `null` тоже не помогает решить проблему. Как можно корректно проверить все 4 случая?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в вашем коде else относится только к последнему условию и срабатывает если хотя бы одно значение не равно нулю

```
if (firstValue == 0 && secondValue !=0) output = Math.sin(secondValue);
else if (secondValue == 0 && firstValue !=0) output = Math.sin(firstValue);
else if (firstValue ==0 && secondValue ==0) output =Math.sin(0);
else alert("Заполните только одно поле!");
```